# What type to cast array of CKRecord.References when adding to Database

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, ckrecord, ckreference

I have a CKRecord type "AccountInfo" which has a field "Wines" with is a list of references to "Wine" records. When I add a new wine, the wine record is added correctly and can reference its vineyard correctly but when I try and update the "AccountInfo" the "Wines" field stays the same.

Here's the code:

```
//reference wine in user record
        //Not working
        let cloudDB = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
        let userRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "AccountInfo", recordID: model.activeUser.recordID)
        var wineRecords: [CKRecord.Reference] = []
        for wine in model.activeUser.wines {
            wineRecords.append(CKRecord.Reference(recordID: wine.recordID, action: .deleteSelf))
        }
        
        userRecord.setValuesForKeys([
            "Wines": wineRecords as NSArray
        ])
        
        let updateWinesList = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: [userRecord])
        updateWinesList.savePolicy = .changedKeys
        
        //save changes to users wine list
        cloudDB.add(updateWinesList)
```

I've tried using `CKModifyRecirdsOperation` and saving the whole record with `cloudDB.save` but nothing has made any changes to the record. So can someone explain how to update a field of type Reference(List) in a CKRecord inside a Cloudkit database.

**Edit:**
The major reason this is confusing me is because in my Wine record I have a field "Vineyard" which references a Vineyard record like so:

```
 let recordToAdd = CKRecord(recordType: "Wine")
        //get Vineyard Record
        recordToAdd.setValuesForKeys([
            "Type": newWine.type,
            "Vintage": newWine.vintage,
            //This works
            "Vineyard": CKRecord.Reference(recordID: vineyard.recordID, action: .deleteSelf)
        ])
```

**Update 1/11**
I've tested out the Modify operation with other fields so I know that it is syntaxically correct so I'm assuming it is an issue with the Type that I cast the array as. So can some provide insight on what the correct type casting is.

Comment: I ran a test on one of my apps using just a Save call on the database and it worked fine. I appended a new ref with         deckRec["courses"] = newCourseRefs instead of setValuesForKeys but it should be the same.

Comment: @john elemans can I see what the code look like just for a reference?

Answer (score 0):

for reference, this code works;

```
func addCourseReferenceToDeck(deckN : Int, courseRef : CKRecord.Reference, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void)
{
    let deckRec = decks[deckN]

    var newCourseRefs = [CKRecord.Reference]()
    if deckRec["courses"] != nil
    {
        newCourseRefs = deckRec["courses"] as! [CKRecord.Reference]
    }
    newCourseRefs.append(courseRef)
    deckRec["courses"] = newCourseRefs
    
    privateDB.save(deckRec, completionHandler:
    {
            (record, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil)
            {
                completion(error)
            }
            else
            {
                //self.decks.append(record!)
                completion(nil)
                
            }
           
    })
}
```

My record for decks has a field "courses" of type [CKRecord.Reference];